# Prism. EventAggregator to currently active tab

Tags: c#, design-patterns, prism, prism-5

I have this UI shell:

[image]

On refresh button, I call `_eventAggregator.GetEvent<RefreshEvent>().Publish();`

And code in all regions in tabs had subscribed to this event.

**Problem:**
The problem is that I want to update only currently active tab. But in my case all tabs are updating. Is there a good practices to solve this?

**Edit 1**

I implement `IActiveAware` in my view:

```
public partial class ShipsControlView : UserControl, IActiveAware
{
    public ShipsControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool isActive;

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isActive;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.isActive == value)
                return;

            this.isActive = value;

            var viewModelActiveAware = this.DataContext as IActiveAware;
            if (viewModelActiveAware != null)
                viewModelActiveAware.IsActive = value;

            this.OnIsActiveChanged();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged;

    protected virtual void OnIsActiveChanged()
    {
        var handler = this.IsActiveChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Added this view to tabControl:

```
<TabControl
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion2"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"
        ></TabControl>
```

.

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion2", typeof(ShipsControlView));
```

I check the status of `IsActive`, it is always changed if I click tabs (works right).

**Problem:**
If tab is not active, the commands in that tab triggering on my global composite button, but it must not.

Comment: A good approach would be to pass a value along with the event i.e. a string value (which can contain, for example,  the name of tab to be active) and then it can be checked in the subscriber's callback, whether or not to update the code in a particular tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the event aggregator for this.  You should be using CompositeCommands.  They even monitor active tabs/VMs when they implement IActiveAware automatically.

Here is the docs: http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/09-Communication/#solution-commanding